# Database Design Help-Online Checkout Project

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a database for an online checkout as a project. This is the first database I've made so go easy on me.

Anyways, I have tables "account", "order", "shopping cart" and "sku". Account holds the shipping info, name, phone, email, etc. The primary key is accountNumber. Order holds the billing information. It's foreign key is accountNumber and it's primary key is OrderID. Shopping Cart only has 2 columns-orderID and skuNumber. OrderID is the foreign key and skuNumber is the primary key. SKU has 4 columns-skuNumber, quanity, price, unit, and totalPrice. skuNumber is foreign and primary key.

My question is- the way I currently have this setup only 1 item sku can be ordered at a time. How would you design this differently so that wasn't necessary? I know I could do sku1, sku2, etc., but that seems like it would be against best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database isn't [***normaized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) by this design, instead of the `SKU` table you will need two extra tables, becouse you simply need to separate the prodcts details(`Name`, `price`, etc...) from the Order details, so you will have to add the following tables:

**Products:**

- `Id`.
- `Name`.
- `Price`.
- ...

Another one `OrderItems` or `SKUItems` that contains the following columns:

- `OrderID` foreign key to the orders table.
- `ProductId` a foreign key to the products table.
- `Quantity`.
- ...

I didn't understand what `SKU` is but if it is some kind of product type, you can add an extra table `ProductTypes: Id, name` that holds product types, this table contains for example a product type called `SKU` then you can add a `ProductTypeId` to your `Products`, so you could have something like:

```
 ProductTypeId  |  Name
------------------------
       1           SKU
```

For the `Products` table:

```
 ID  |   Name  | ProductTypeId
-----------------------------
 1       SKU1        1
 2       SKU2        1
 3       SKU3        1
```

Comment: what should I have for a primary key in the OrderItems table? Also, a SKU is like a bar code.

Comment: @cmorris1441, Well, you have two choices the first is to use two fields `ProductId` and `OrderId` as a primary key, the second is to use [Surrogate Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) something like `OrderItemId`.

Comment: I dont like the idea of a productId in a OrderItemTable. What if the product changes title, price or other properties. The OrderItem could live for months, even in history after submitting order. That would be a misleading order history page